# React Autosuggest Search Box using Redux on TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am using typescript for it Not Babel, new to it hence no idea if there is any link for the application using React+Redux on TypeScript for AutoSuggest Search Box please help me on this ..

Comment: Help you on what? The question is not clear

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda: are you having any link with you , that can help me to build the React auto-suggest seacrh application ..?

Comment: Unfortunately, the project I worked on is not public on the web. But I can say that the autosuggest documentation is pretty decent. I suggest you to take some time to read their docs and try some basic examples on your own.